# SharePoint 2013 Aug 2017 CU messed up our search settings

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, cumulative-update

After applying the Aug 8th 2017 CU for SharePoint 2013 our search pages, settings, and query's have changed and a great deal of content is not working properly.

Also I am now noticing that under the search input box there is an option to View Results in English with a drop down that allows the users specify their language of choice, I haven't been able to find anywhere to turn this unwanted feature off, our search results page uses the `_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx` page to return results, also any attempt to recreate this page with the web parts does not return any results.

Any one else notice these alterations?